# Cat * and order of similarly named files

Tags: bash, cat

I download a number of log files, but they are auto named during download so the order is incorrect:

```
21-Jan-2020 20:01.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 2.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 3.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 4.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 5.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03.log
21-Jan-2020 20:04.log
```

Note how the `21-Jan-2020 20:02.log` comes after the `21-Jan-2020 20:02 1.log`, and also the `21-Jan-2020 20:03.log` after the `21-Jan-2020 20:03 1.log`, etc.
The correct order would be:

```
21-Jan-2020 20:01.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 2.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 3.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 4.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 5.log
21-Jan-2020 20:04.log
```

One option would be to rename the files, but I am trying to use `cat`.

When I use `cat *.log > all.log` the date timestamps of the logs files are out of order, because the files are out of order.

I would like to fix the order somehow. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796743/cat-and-order-of-files) but I failed to change so it fits my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sort -V`

Putting the file names in a file called `list.txt`, and then doing the below :

```
cat list.txt | sort -V
```

produces the order you want :

```
21-Jan-2020 20:01.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02.log
21-Jan-2020 20:02 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 1.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 2.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 3.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 4.log
21-Jan-2020 20:03 5.log
21-Jan-2020 20:04.log
```

From `man sort` :

> -V, --version-sort natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: `cat $(ls | sort -V)`

Comment: @Veda errm..nope

Comment: This will fail when you have other months and other years.

Comment: @kvantour I agree, however coincidentally this version sorting of `sort` command could quickly solve the OP's problem with the current names as demonstrated..

Comment: @nullPointer Why not? Saving the files first to a file does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @Veda there are spaces in the filenames. This won't work. In my answer I just used a file containing the filenames for demo purposes of `sort -V`

Answer (score 0):

> **Pathname Expansion**
>
> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters `*`, `?`, and `[`.  If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and **replaced with an alphabetically sorted list** of file names matching the pattern.
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

Since a <space> is [alphabetically](http://www.asciitable.com/) before a <dot>, you get the list you expect.

Furthermore, the data-format which is used in your filenames is also not sortable. Imagine you will get a file "21-Feb-2020 20:01.log". It will be listed before all files from January. It is always good to make use of sortable date-time formats. A common example would be `YYYYMMDDhhmm.log`, and since you make use of a sequence counter in there, you might want to concider filenames like `YYYYMMDDhhmm_nn.log` where `nn` is a number starting from `00`.

We could come up with a fascinating rule how to get your files in proper order. Nonetheless, I would suggest to quickly rename your files:

```
for file in *.log; do
   read date time seq <<<"${file%.log}"
   file_new="$(printf "%s_%0.2d.log" "$(date -d "$date $time" '+%FT%H:%M')" "${seq}")"
   mv "${file}" "${file_new}"
done
```

You can also just make a softlink to `/path/to/tempdir` with that name.

And then you can do

```
cat *.log > full.log
```

**remark:** If you only care about merging the files of the same day, the solution of nullPointer works.